# How is C# dictionary variable stored in memory?

Tags: c#, memory-management, collections

Can anyone explain me how C# dictionary stored in memory?  I do know that in C# memory management is done using heap and stack. But I really couldn't find a simple explanation on how memory is allocated when dictionary variable is created, is it created in stack frame or heap space?

Comment: Dictionary is a reference type, all reference types are stored in managed heap

Comment: As @PavelAnikhouski mentioned **heap** is more or less responsible for keeping track of our objects , our data, as the **Dictionary** you are asking for.

Here you have an [article about Heap&Stack](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/C-Sharp-heaping-vs-stacking-in-net-part-i/)

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you need to be **very** clear about what you're asking here; do you mean the *dictionary*? or the *variable*? because they're two *completely different things*.

The *dictionary* is an object on the managed heap.

The *variable* (the reference to the object on the managed heap) - could mean a "local", a "parameter", or a "field". Fields are *wherever they are*, and depends on the thing having the field (reference-type, vs non-boxed value-type (which may or may not itself be a field on something), vs boxed value-type). Could be heap or stack. Parameters and locals are *usually* on the stack, except when they are *captured* into a state context (async methods, anonymous methods / lambdas, iterator blocks, local functions), in which case they are actually treated as fields; and the "fields on what" depends on the exact context (local functions are structs, for example). Also note that the stack is an implementation detail!

But you *probably* mean "the dictionary itself", in which case: managed heap.

Comment: But what about `ValueTask` ? :-)

Comment: @Jodrell what about it? I mean... it is an interesting topic, but it didn't seem to be relevant to the question

Comment: With reference to "Parameters and locals are usually on the stack, except when they are captured into a state context (async methods, anonymous methods / lambdas, iterator blocks, local functions)", do async methods that return `ValueTask` capture into a state context?

Comment: @Jodrell *yes*, but the machinery is much more complex to describe - and depends on the runtime version; if the async method turns out to be sync, it shouldn't need an object; when it does, it *might* become boxed, or it *might* use a recycled state object - there's a complex change in .NET 5 about whether to do that or not, or I have some optional tools that enable it; either way, once it goes async it'll be on the managed heap, but that *may or may not* be a new allocation

Answer (score 3):

You can always check the Reference Source to see most of .NET implementations:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0

All of the entries in the Dictionary are structs for example, so, they are going to be handled like ones:

```
private struct Entry {
        public int hashCode;    // Lower 31 bits of hash code, -1 if unused
        public int next;        // Index of next entry, -1 if last
        public TKey key;           // Key of entry
        public TValue value;         // Value of entry
    }
```